# button with shadow and drawable

Tags: android, xml

i want how to make button like this shape with shadow and drawable

[image]

Comment: Don't just repeat the same text a bunch of time to avoid SO restrictions

Comment: Also, what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Use below drawable file in your view background.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/grey"/>
        <!--shadow Color-->
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:bottom="3dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        //background color
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: thanks but i want to set drawable with pic as background like the above picture